# How to get the output using jq for a json array for each value

Tags: shell, jq

I have a JSON file where items is an array and it has `name` three times in it.

How do I iterate the loop using shell script so that using a single script, it outputs the value of `name` for all the names in the array?

In my case, I should get the value of `name` three times.

Here is what I am doing right now:

```
curl ***** | jq '.items[0].name'
curl ***** | jq '.items[1].name'
curl ***** | jq '.items[2].name'
```

How can I create a script that automatically fetches however many times `name` appears in the `items` array and then prints them one by one? Is it possible using some `for` or `while` loop?

Comment: Why not just `jq '.items[].name'`

Comment: Ah thanks! That did the trick!